# Booking Dates Availability Ranges in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, between

I have two fields, check_in and nights.

Nights are inclusive of the check_in date. So if a customer books 1 night, he would then check_out the following day and the room would then be available for booking (unless already booked by somebody else).

Here is an example of a couple records within my table,

```
customer          room            check_in            nights
cus1              test room       2013-01-23          2
cus2              test room       2013-01-25          1
cus3              test room       2013-01-26          4
```

cus3 has booked a room, they will check into the room on 2013-01-26 and they will stay for 4 nights. this means the room will be unavailable for booking during this time.

So how would I check whether the room was available?

the room should only be available for check_in on 2013-01-30.

All help is appreciated :)

Comment: Do you want to check when the room will next be available (e.g., from the current date)? Or do you want to check whether the room is available for a given date?

Comment: @StephenBooher I would like to pass a given date and if possible, return true if the room is available and false if the room is not available.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the data for the customer row, use this to get the check out date:

```
$check_out = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['check_in'].' + '.$row['nights'].' days'));
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this,

```
SELECT room, 
       CASE WHEN 'dateHere' BETWEEN check_in AND check_out
           THEN 'UNAVAILABLE'
           ELSE 'AVAILABLE'
       END Status
FROM
  (
      SELECT  room, 
              check_in, 
              DATE_ADD(check_in, INTERVAL nights day) check_out
      FROM    booking
  ) s
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*showing unavailable*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d6fb/5)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*all are available*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d6fb/4)

Comment: Thats almost perfect, I forgot to add that I will be sending a date and the amount of nights requested. So if x date is available with x amount of nights

Comment: could you give an example?

Comment: (using my existing data provided as an example). Customer would like to book a room and check_in on 2013-01-21, they would like to stay for 4 days. They shouldn't be able to book the room as there are existing bookings within that range.

Comment: how about you make a stored procedure out of this query, [<< CLICK HERE >>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d6fb/17)

Comment: I don't have permission to create stored procedures I don't think :(. Also looking at your example, if there are thousands of bookings, it looks like it would return every row, i would only like it to return whether 'test room' is available. I have a list of rooms say, room1,room2,room3,room4. I need to return what rooms out of that list are available for the given date and nights.

Comment: ok this will only return rooms that are available, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d6fb/20

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22526/discussion-between-verheesj-and-jw)

Answer (score 0):

There’s a great site with a list of MySQL statements for common scenarios. Checking whether a room is available within a given period is one of them: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#576

Answer (score 0):

When you select your check in date and nights occupied you can do something like this (dummy code):

```
    $startDate='2013-01-26';//for example
    $to_time=date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$startDate + 4 day"));
    echo $to_time;//prints 2013-01-30
```